# Gremlin, combine two queries and join data

Tags: join, graph, gremlin

I have a problem making a query for the following case:

```
     +--------------------hasManager-------------------+
     |                         |                       |
     |           property:isPersonalMngr=true (bool)   |
     |                                                 v
[ Employee ]-- hasShift -->[ Shift ]-- hasManager -->[ Manager ]
                 |           |           |
                 |           |       property:isPersonalMngr=false (bool)
                 |           |
                 |     property:name (text)
                 |             
         property:baseShift (bool)
```

For a manager 'John', who is managing shifts and can also be a personal manager  of an empoyee, I want return all the employees he's managing with the list of shifts for each employee. Each empoyee has a 'baseShift' (say: 'night' / 'day') and a scheduled shift ('wed123')

Eg:

```
[ 'Employee1', [ 'night', 'wed123', 'sat123' ]]
[ 'Employee2', [ 'day', 'mon123', 'tue123' ]]
```

For the shift employees I have this:

```
g.V('John').in('hasManager').in('hasShift').hasLabel('Employee')
```

For the personal managed I have this:

```
g.V('John').in('hasManager').hasLabel('Employee')
```

How do I combine these two AND add the name property of the shift in a list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, I created the following graph. Hope this fits your data model from above:

```
g.addV('Manager').property(id,'John').as('john').
    addV('Manager').property(id,'Terry').as('terry').
    addV('Manager').property(id,'Sally').as('sally').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Tom').as('tom').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Tim').as('tim').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Lisa').as('lisa').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Sue').as('sue').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Chris').as('chris').
    addV('Employee').property(id,'Bob').as('bob').
    addV('Shift').property('name','mon123').as('mon123').
    addV('Shift').property('name','tues123').as('tues123').
    addV('Shift').property('name','sat123').as('sat123').
    addV('Shift').property('name','wed123').as('wed123').
    addE('hasManager').from('tom').to('john').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasManager').from('tim').to('john').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasManager').from('lisa').to('terry').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasManager').from('sue').to('terry').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasManager').from('chris').to('sally').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasManager').from('bob').to('sally').property('isPersonalMngr',true).
    addE('hasShift').from('tom').to('mon123').property('baseShift','day').
    addE('hasShift').from('tim').to('tues123').property('baseShift','night').
    addE('hasShift').from('lisa').to('wed123').property('baseShift','night').
    addE('hasShift').from('sue').to('sat123').property('baseShift','night').
    addE('hasShift').from('chris').to('wed123').property('baseShift','day').
    addE('hasShift').from('bob').to('sat123').property('baseShift','day').
    addE('hasShift').from('bob').to('mon123').property('baseShift','day').
    addE('hasShift').from('tim').to('wed123').property('baseShift','day').
    addE('hasManager').from('mon123').to('terry').property('isPersonalMngr',false).
    addE('hasManager').from('tues123').to('sally').property('isPersonalMngr',false).
    addE('hasManager').from('wed123').to('john').property('isPersonalMngr',false).
    addE('hasManager').from('sat123').to('terry').property('isPersonalMngr',false)
```

From this, the follow query generates an output in the format that you're looking for:

```
gremlin> g.V('John').
    union(
        inE('hasManager').has('isPersonalMngr',true).outV(),
        inE('hasManager').has('isPersonalMngr',false).outV().in('hasShift')).
    dedup().
    map(union(id(),out('hasShift').values('name').fold()).fold())
==>[Tom,[mon123]]
==>[Tim,[tues123,wed123]]
==>[Lisa,[wed123]]
==>[Chris,[wed123]]
```

A note on your data model - you could likely simplify things by having two different types of edges for `hasManager` and that would remove the need for a boolean property on those edges.  Instead, you could have `hasOrgManager` and `hasShiftManager` edges and that would remove the need for the property checks when traversing those edges.